# Deploying Rails App with Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, passenger

I tried to deploy my rails application with passenger and apache and I get the following error message.

```
/root/finalProject/app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page]) ^ /root/finalProject/app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting kEND @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page]) ^
```

The code of the static_pages_controller.rb is the following

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    if signed_in?
      @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the same ruby version on both production and development?

Try changing

```
@feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

to

```
@feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(:page=>params[:page])
```

Answer (score 3):

Try typing `ruby -v` on the command line. I bet you're using 1.8, which doesn't allow the hash syntax you're trying to use here. Try this instead:

```
@feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```